# What is input overdrive?

Tags: operational-amplifier, common-mode

I'm looking for an affordable op-amp to be used as a low-frequency (<100Hz) low-output-power (5V 1mA) rail-to-rail voltage follower that can run on -0/+5Vdc. So far my best bet looks like the MCP6002 which approaches the rails within 25mV. The common-mode input and output swing are way better than LM* devices in the same price range. However, the output swing specification is curious:

[image: overdrive spec]

What does overdrive mean in this context?

The input is expected to frequently visit either 0V or Vdd=5.0V, which - if I read the spec correctly - this device can tolerate. The loss of 25mV on both ends is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer from [here](https://www.edaboard.com/threads/what-is-output-overdrive-of-an-opamp.275900/)

> Overdrive means that the input signal is the maximum and drives the
> output to the lowest output voltage. See figure 2-33 on page 10 of the
> [Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21314g.pdf).

Comment: So reading from that sheet, overdrive actually looks to be the amount that the input signal exceeds Vdd. Am I wrong?

Comment: It looks like it yes, but still its not clear enough for me. I just had the same question as you, you seem to be the only one asking

Answer (score -1):

Input overdrive means the opamp internal circuitry is overdriven, which ensures the output transistors (FETs in this case) are very very strongly **ON** and thus are in TRIODE region where the appropriate FET (a pullup device, hence Pchannel here) is well modeled as a very low value resistor.

Notice the datasheet refers to "VDD = 5.5 volts".

This is not how you are planning to power your circuit.

However, your load is only 0.001 amp, and at 5volt, the equivalent Rload is 5,000 ohms.

Since you have not specified how close to 5.000 volts you must be, the design cannot be completed.

Comment: My Vdd will be 5.0V, and the input will frequently be equal to Vdd - I've edited my question to show that. When you ask how close, do you mean the output? Getting to within 25mV of 5V on the output is fine.

Comment: What exterior conditions cause overdrive?